# Adjust formula for two cells that are 0 in iWork

Tags: macos, formula, iwork

I need help adding another rule to my formula, I need it to also say 
IF `U17` and `X17` both have `0` in them, then leave `blank`

Formula `Y17`

```
IF(OR(U17="",X17=""),"",IF(X17+V17=U17,"Push", IF(X17+V17>U17,W17,T17)))
```

If two cells have `0`, then leave `blank` and also if two cells are `blank` to leave `blank`

Thanks

Comment: Please do not cross post questions on SE sites. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296469/adjust-formula-to-add-if-2-cells-are-0-leave-blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the AND function.

```
IF(OR(U17="",X17="",AND(U17=0,X17=0)),"",IF(X17+V17=U17,"Push", IF(X17+V17>U17,W17,T17)))
```

this will leave blank if either u17 or x17 is blank or both of them are 0

if you want to leave blank only if both of them are blank or both of them are 0 then the function is

```
IF(OR(AND(U17="",X17=""),AND(U17=0,X17=0)),"",IF(X17+V17=U17,"Push", IF(X17+V17>U17,W17,T17)))
```

you didn't specify in your request which one do you need.

Answer (score 1):

The formula can be simplified to this:

`IFERROR(IF(OR(A2,B2),A2+B2,""),"")`

Since `0` is resolves to `false` and `OR` takes Boolean values, just check for `0` in both cells and return the empty string.  Otherwise, if both are empty, the `IFERROR` will return the empty string as, for some reason, an empty string in Numbers is not treated as a Boolean `false` like in programming languages such as JavaScript.

See the example below.  This will work in Numbers on macOS or iOS.

[image: Table showing results of formula]

[image: Formula]